# Explain htaccess rewrite condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in current project I have following rewrite option. On production server everythnig works fine, but on local  allways get 404. I think, that problem could be in this rewrite condition. Can someone explain how this works?

```
RewriteCond ${rewrite:%{REQUEST_URI}|notfound} !=notfound
RewriteRule (.*) ${rewrite:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

and then...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^\/|\.]+)/([^\/|\.]+/)*([^\/|\.]+)/?$
RewriteCond ${multishop:%1|notfound} !=notfound
RewriteCond ${kategorie:%3|notfound} !=notfound
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?${multishop:%1}&cat=${kategorie:%3} [L,QSA]
```

Can Apache configuration affect this?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax of conditions suggests that most likely **you have [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) defined** in the Apache config of production server.